# Order depending on json data in varchar field

Tags: mysql, json, sorting

I have a mysql table like the following

```
id | name | data
```

Where `data` is holding a json object like the following:

```
{
    type: test,
    number: 5
}
```

I there a way to sort the row depending on the `number` in the JSON object?

I know that I can do it programmatically, but I was just wondering if there was an SQL alternative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way of doing it

```
select * from table_name
order by 
CAST(substring_index(substring_index(data,'number:',-1),'}',1) as UNSIGNED);
```

**[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/552f8b/5)**